# Deploying Grails app on Cloud Foundry

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I developed a Grails app using spring source to deploy it on cloud foundry. It seems that it has been deployed well but the url does not work. Could some one help me!
Thanks,
Reza

Comment: Please give more details. What is the URL of the app? What do the log files show?

Comment: it is http://multisite.cloudfoundry.com/  and I got 404 notfound on the page.

Comment: try calling 'grails cf-logs' using the grails cloud foundry plugin, it will tell you how your application failed.

Answer (score 1):

To access your log files using the grails plugin, use grails cf-logs.

That will surely show you how your application is behaving.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have pointed out use

```
grails cf-logs
```

to see the logging results of your app.

It may also have happend that your application didn't start up properly. So try to restart it by typing:

```
grails cf-stop
grails cf-start
```

The Cloud Foundry plugin/Grails console may get stale while starting the app ("`Starting app .........`") but just keep hitting the deployment URL and as soon it's running you can quit and restart Grails.